# Can't fetch value after changing value of text

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

If I click the Edit Button a modal pop ups, and when I click the Save Changes Button right away I can just fetch the ID, Title and Archive BUT whenever I change the value of the text box(Title), I can't fetch the ID(user) and the Archive(0 or 1) but I can fetch the Title. How was this even possible?

I passed the data from the Database to the Edit Button:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right edit-modal" 
    data-archive="@y" data-status="@item.status" data- 
    title="@item.discussion_title" 
    data-id="@item.offered_course_discussion_id" data-toggle="modal" data- 
    target="#NotArchiveModal"> 
        Edit
    </button>
```

This is my modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade edit-modal" id="NotArchiveModal" tabindex="-1" 
      role="dialog" aria-labelledby="NotArchiveModal" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit 
                          Topic 
                      </h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data- 
                      dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                       <input type="hidden" 
                       id="offered_course_discussion_id" 
                       name="offered_course_discussion_id" value="" />
                       <input type="text" id="item_discussion_title" 
                       name="item_discussion_title" class="form-control" 
                       value="" />
                       <div class="form-check">
                           <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
                           id="offered_course_discussion_archive" 
                           name="archive" value="">
                           <label class="form-check-label" 
                           for="defaultCheck1">
                               @thread Thread
                           </label>
                           <br />
                           <button type="submit" id="submitChanges" 
                           onclick="myfunction()" value="click" class="btn 
                           btn-primary">
                               Save changes
                           </button>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".edit-modal", function () {
        var title = $(this).data('title');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var archive = $(this).data('archive');

        $(".modal-body #item_discussion_title").val(title);
        $(".modal-body #offered_course_discussion_id").val(id);
        $(".modal-body #offered_course_discussion_archive").val(archive);    
});

    function myfunction() {
        var id = $(".modal-body #offered_course_discussion_id").val();
        var title = $(".modal-body #item_discussion_title").val();
        var archive = $(".modal-body 
        #offered_course_discussion_archive").val();
        alert("ID: " + id + " Title: " + title + " Archive: " + archive);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'UpdateTopic',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "title": title,
                "archive": archive
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }


</script>
```

My Controller:

```
    public JsonResult UpdateTopic(int id, string title, int archive)
    {

    }
```

Comment: try fetching the values using `$(this).attr('data-id');`.

Comment: Still wont work, it gives me undefined value.

Comment: The before clicking the `button` with class`.edit-modal` do a inspect element on it see wither it have any attribute values matching to your `data-*` attributes.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes the OP is looking for it but he is using the `HTML` attribute to set the value instead of setting the value in js as `$(control).data('key','value');` That's why I suggested to go for the `CSS3`attribute selection  approach.